# "Rant & rave" usage

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I often hear the phrase "rant & rave" used in the negative sense, as in:

*Bob would often steer the conversation off course, ranting and raving about rush hour traffic that morning.*

But "rave" (when used alone) has an unambiguously positive connotation (e.g., Sarah *raved* about the delicious tomato soup). And "rant" used alone seems to mean essentially the same thing as "rant AND rave."

**My question:** is it correct to use the phrase "rant & rave" when you're *only* complaining, or should you use the phrase when you have both praise *and* criticism to heap upon something?

Comment: It's idiomatic, so you can't really analyse the words separately.

Comment: I'm asking about the usage of the phrase, not individual analysis of the words

Comment: Your penultimate paragraph looks at the individual meanings. Sorry for getting confused!

Comment: No worries, @marcellothearcane!

Comment: Hello, Will. Questions on ELU (which is aimed at linguists) are supposed to be accompanied by reasonable research. Look up the definition of the expression 'rant and rave' in a dictionary such as [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rant_and_rave).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic expression dates back to the 17th century and means *to shout angrily and wildly*. The expression is generally used with a negative connotation, ***but to “rave” isn’t quite as positive as you seem to believe.***

According to the following extract from [The Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2011/03/rant-and-rave.html) both terms are used with the negative connotations that were in vogue at that time:

> ***The verb “rave” can be negative as well as positive.*** You can rave in anger about something or rave in praise of it.
>
> - The verb “rave” has undergone a few changes over the centuries. Let’s follow its history, with a few interruptions along the way.
>     When “rave” came into English in the 1300s, it didn’t involve shouting or other forms of self-expression.
>     It meant “to be mad, to show signs of madness or delirium,” according to the Oxford English Dictionary.
> - The word’s origins are uncertain, but there’s a connection with “reverie,” which originally meant wild and uncontrolled behavior.
>     “Reverie” came into English in the 1300s from Middle French, where it implied madness, delirium, wandering of the mind, and so on.
>     ***Going back to “rave,” the OED says it developed new senses in the 1500s and 1600s, when it came to mean “to rage furiously or intensely” and “to speak or declaim wildly, irrationally, or incoherently.”***
>
> ***These are the senses of the word used in the expression “rant and rave,” which was first recorded in the 1600s.***

To rant has a later origin and dates back from the early 17th century:

> To  “rant,” a word dating from 1602. It came from the Dutch randen (to talk foolishly or rave).
>
> - To “rant,” according to the OED, originally meant “to talk or declaim in an extravagant or hyperbolical manner; to use bombastic language; (esp. of an actor) to orate or speak in a melodramatic or grandiose style.”
> - ***Later, in the mid-1600s, ranting became angrier. “Rant” came to mean “to speak furiously; to storm or rage violently.”***
>
> ***So to “rant and rave” means***, in the words of the OED, “to talk or declaim hyperbolically, wildly, or furiously, now esp. as if mad or delirious.”

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

Rant means speak or shout at length in an angry, impassioned way.
Rave means talk incoherently, as if one were delirious or mad.

Therefore "rant and rave" when used together make sense used in a negative manner. "Bob would often steer the conversation off course, ranting and raving about rush hour traffic that morning." This shows he is frustrated with so much early morning hustle. He probably likes a quiet drive which he doesn't get.

If using Rave individually, it can be used in any sense. Like Rave parties which are quite wild and make you go wild with energy and atmosphere. But Rant itself has negativity in it, so it cant be used in a positive manner unless that negativity is used for a good cause.